# Jenkins and Maven profiles

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, build, devops

We are working on a legacy project and the first task is to setup a DevOps for the same.
The important thing is we are very new to this area.

We are planning to use jenkins and sonarqube for the purpose initially. Let me start with the requirements.

- Currently the the project is sub divided into multiple projects (not modules)
- We had to follow this build structure as there are no plans for re-organising it as a single multimodule maven project
- Currently the builds and dependencies are managed manually

Eg: The project is subdivided in to 5 multi-module maven projects,
   say A,B,C,D and E

```
        1. A and C are completely independent and can be easly built
        2. B depends on the artifact generated by A (jar) and has multiple maven profiles (say tomcat and websphere, it is a webservice module)
        3. D depends on the artifact generated by C 
        4. E depends on A, B and D and has multiple maven profiles (say tomcat and websphere, it is a web project)
```

Based on jenkins documentation to handle this scenario, we are thinking about parameterized builds using “parameterized build plugin" and "extended choice parameter plugin" with the help of these plugins we are able to parameterize the profile name. But before each build, the builder waits for the profile parameter.

So we are still searching to find an good solution to

```
    1. keep the dependency between projects an built the whole projects if there is any change in SCM (SVN). For that we are used "Build whenever a SNAPSHOT dependency is built" and "SCM polling option". Unfortunately this option seems not working in our case (we have given an interval of 5 min for scm polling but no build is happening based on test commits)

    2. Even though we are able to parameterize the profile, this seems as a manual step (is there an option to automate this part too, ie. build with tomcat profile and websphere profile should happen sequentially).
```

We are struggling to find a solution to cater all these core requirements. Any pointer would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
San

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:**
Jenkins 2 is out and has a built-in support for [pipelines](https://jenkins.io/2.0/#pipelines).

---

A few pointers for your requirements:

1. **"built the whole projects if there is any change in SCM"**

   - Although `Poll SCM` usually requires less work, the proper way to do it is to use SVN hooks.

     The solution works as follows:

     - First you enable the `Trigger builds remotely` feature and enter a random token in `Authentication Token`.
     - This allows you to trigger builds remotely using Jenkins REST API (`http[s]://JENKINS_URL/job/BUILD_NAME/build?token=TOKEN`)
     - Then you create a SVN hook (a script that runs whenever you commit) which triggers the build by sending a request to that URL (using curl,wget, python,...).

       There are a lot of manuals on how to create SVN hooks, here's the [first result on "SVN Hooks" from Google](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.reposadmin.create.html#svn.reposadmin.create.hooks).
2. **"keep the dependency between projects"**

   - I would create a different Jenkins Job for each project separately, then make sure builds are executed in the required order.
   - I think the best way to order your builds (dependencies) is to create a `Build Pipeline` using the [Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin) (previously known as Workflow Plugin).

     There is a lot to explain here, so it's better you read on your own. You can start [here](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/).

     There are also other (simpler) solutions, like [Build Flow Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) or [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) which can help create dependencies between builds, but I think `Pipeline` is the newest and considered a best practice (it's definitely the most advanced solution).

     Still, having said that, if you feel `Pipeline` is an overkill for you, go for the alternatives.
   - I would recommend making sure each build does a `mvn install` to the same local repo, and also deploys the artifact to `Artifactory` (hopefully you have one).
3. **Automate parameterized builds: "build with tomcat profile and websphere profile"**

   - To do that you'll need to create `parameterized builds`.
   - That's pretty easy to do, you just check `This build is parameterized` in your build config and add a MVN_PROFILE string/choice parameter.
   - After that you can trigger each build several times, with different parameters, using any one of the plugins mentioned in the previous bullet.

**Extra Tip:**

While hacking your way through this, consider using [Job Configuration History Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/JobConfigHistory+Plugin), it can help review and revert changes made to the configuration.

Good luck, hope this helps :)

Answer (score 5):

My maven knowledge is limited, however since you didnt get any response yet, ill try to give some general advice.

There are usually multiple ways to reach some aim in Jenkins, each has its pros and cons. Choosing the most fitting solution depends on the specific requirements and your environment/setup.

However you first need something that just works, then you can refine it.

A quick result you get with the following

### Everything in one job

> - Configure your subversion repo (Multiple are possible) to be checked out into your workspace
> - Enable *Poll SCM* trigger
> - Build your modules/projects via *Execute shell* build steps. (Failed builds can be handed to the job result by using `Exit 1` on a `Execute shell` Build step.)

However keep in mind that this will prevent advanced functionality on a per project/module basis, such as mail notifications to the dev to blame. Or trend of metrics, like warnings or static code analysis.

The following solution is easier to extend in that direction.

### Wrapper job around your various build jobs

> - Use Build step *Trigger/call builds on other projects* to build `A`, archive needed artifacts
> - Use Build step *Trigger/call builds on other projects* with some parameter `tomcat`to build `B tomcat` version, use [Copy Artifact Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin) to copy over jar from `A`
> - ...
> - Use Build step *Trigger/call builds on other projects* with some parameter `tomcat`to build `E tomcat` version. Use Copy Artifact Plugin to copy all needed artifacts, you can specify parameter there if you need artifact of i.e. `B tomcat` version

In this setup, monitoring the svn is an issue since if you trigger it from polling SCM, it will checkout it in your wrapper workspace while you dont actually need it checked out there, but in your build jobs.

Possible solution: Share the workspace between wrapper job and your build jobs, so the duplicate checkouts in the build jobs will find the files already in the right revision. However then you *need+ to make sure the downstream jobs are executed on the same machine (there are plugins to do so)

Or even more elegant: Use a *post-commit hook* (See [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Subversion+Plugin), section Post-comit hook) on your svn to notify jenkins of changes.

*Edit:* For the future, its worth looking into the [Pipeline Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin) and its [documentation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-plugin/blob/master/TUTORIAL.md) for more complex builds, this is the engine for the upcoming jenkins version 2.0, see [here](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/2.0+Pipeline+as+Code).

Answer (score 3):

I would create 5 different jobs for ABCDE.

As you mentioned A and C would be standalone jobs so I would just do mvn clean install/pkg/verify based on your need.

For B I would first build A and then invoke another maven target in build to build B

For D, I would first build C and then build D

Finally for E , i would use invoke top level mvn targets 5 times A , B,C,D and finally E

Answer (score 1):

I would consider a bit different approach to fully de-couple the projects.
If you are able to create your internal artifactory, than I would consider in the maven build each on of the dependencies as a third party library exactly like it is done with any other external libraries you are using.
This way, each such project can be seperatly built and stored in the artifactory and when a dependent project will be built it will just take the right version as mentioned in the pom file.
This way you'll have different build process for each one of the projects and only relevant projects (relevant = changed) will be built.